# Compiling c# code with icon using powershell or batch

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file

I need to make a .exe file from c# code and also add an icon. But I have to do this using batch or powershell. I have looked all over the internet and have come to no conclusion. Would really like some help on how to do this. Thanks, CollinScripter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried `/win32icon` option?

```
csc /win32icon:rf.ico in.cs
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aaxe43f.aspx